# Ajax callback from the edit action in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

**controllers/admin/products_controller.rb**

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @admin_product.update(admin_product_params)
       format.html { redirect_to @admin_product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
       format.js
    else
       format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end   
end
```

**views/admin/products/update.js.erb**

```
$('#product_table tr.product-<%= @admin_product.id %>').replaceWith(<%=j render 'table_row', admin_product: @admin_product %>);
```

**The response**

```
$('#product_table tr.product-63').replaceWith(<tr class=\"product-63\">\n  <td>12321321<\/td>\n  <td>8asfdasfdsaafsfdsafdsa<\/td>\n  <td>7.00 <i class=\"fa fa-rub\"><\/i><\/td>\n  <td>7.00 <i class=\"fa fa-rub\"><\/i><\/td>\n  <td>6.01 <i class=\"fa fa-rub\"><\/i><\/td>\n  <td><a data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#productEditModal\" data-remote=\"/admin/products/63/edit #productEditForm\", data-title=\"ABC\" class=\"btn btn-mini\">Edit Meh<\/a><\/td>\n  <td><button class=\'deleteButton\' data-delete-button=\'<a class=\"btn btn-danger destroyButton\" data-remote=\"true\" rel=\"nofollow\" data-method=\"delete\" href=\"/admin/products/63\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"><\/i><\/a>\'><\/button><\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n);
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: I think you'll need to give us a bit more to work with here @Xavier.  Is the response what you expect and the page is just not getting updated?  If so, do you have an element with ID 'product_table' which contains a table row with class 'product-63'?  Does jQuery work in general in your application?

Comment: @steveklein Thanks for asking, the response is what i expect it's just not putting the erb code into the page, i've tried just a general `$('body').append('<%= puts "abc" %>'); and even that fails.  Everything is as you expect there is a table with the ID of product_table, a table row with the class product-63.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realised my mistake when rendering the template i forgot to enclose the call in "" or '' thus it was failing silently.

```
$('#product_table tr.product-<%= @admin_product.id %>').replaceWith('<%=j render 'table_row', admin_product: @admin_product %>');
```

Moral of the story is, ensure you don't overlook the little details.

Also turning on XML Http Requests is a huge help;

[image]